# Prevent downtime using lftp mirror

Tags: deployment, lftp

I'm using lftp to deploy a website via Travis CI. There is a build process before the deployment, for that reason a build directory is present and pushed to the root of the ftp server.

```
lftp $FTP_URL -e "glob -d mirror build . --reverse --delete-first --parallel=10 && exit"
```

It works quite well, but I dislike to have a downtime / temporary PHP parse errors because of missing files on my website. What is the best way to work arround that issue?

---

My first approach was an option to set a temporary directory, but the lftp man page says there is only a options for temporary files. I still tried the option but it didn't help.

---

My second approach was to use "mirror build temp" to use a temporary folder and then replace the root with it. The problem here is, that I cannot exclude the temp folder while deleting the old files and folders like rm -rf *.

Comment: Have you tried xfer:use-temp-file setting?

Comment: Do you have access to the parent directory of the web root?

Comment: Temp file setting does not work for a directory. I have no access to the parent directory, the idea was to have separate access for each cronjob - giving access to the parent directory may solve my issue but the ftp user does have access to other projects then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a zero downtown pattern - each placeholder should be replaced:

```
lftp $FTP_URL -e "mirror {SOURCE} {TARGET}-new-{TIMESTAMP} --reverse --delete-first;
mv {TARGET} {TARGET}-old-{TIMESTAMP};
mv {TARGET}-new-{TIMESTAMP} {TARGET};
rm -rf {TARGET}-old-{TIMESTAMP};
exit"
```

Answer (score 2):

For small changes not involving adding/removing php files `set xfer:use-temp-file` should be sufficient. Also don't use `--remove-first`, as it causes lftp to delete obsolete files before uploading.

For larger changes I'd create a separate directory for each version of the site and redirect the web server to the directory using .htaccess [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or some other configuration file. This technique will allow atomic switch to the new version (and back if needed). Besides, you will be able to do final pre-production testing of the new version if you redirect to the new version conditionally based on your IP address or using some other rule.

If you don't want to re-upload whole site for each new version and the FTP server supports [FXP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) with itself, then you can copy old version to a new directory using `mirror old_directory ftp://user@example.com/new_directory`, then update the new directory using `mirror -eR local_dir new_directory`.